# multiple users chat receiving on action-cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I have created one project where I have one customer and another contractor. I implemented ruby on rails `actioncable` for chat. All it is going good but issue is coming when two different people chat with one person, that person is receiving both messages in socket window.  I realised that I have setup `conversation-#{user_id}` as a channel, so user is listening on this channel now two people send chat to him, they both will come on same channel. How can I avoid this? or can I add another user in channel string, but I found it is very difficult. Any idea where I have to send params to subscribe method.

connection

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_session_user
    end

    def find_session_user
      current_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:actioncable_user_id])
      current_user || reject_unauthorized_connection
    end
end
```

My conversation channel

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversations-#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def speak(data)
    message_params = data["message"].each_with_object({}) do |el, hash|
      hash[el.values.first] = el.values.last
    end
  end

    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{current_user.id}",
      message: message_params,
    )
end
```

This code is just condense version, but as it will start conversation-user_id as a channel, so definitely when it is connected and other people send message, this user will receive them in same socket. so I have to do like `conversation-user_id-anotehr_user. Right now it is working on web/mobile and all good, but when two user communicate with one user it create issue by displaying two users chat on one socket.

Any idea how can I create such channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by binding chat with 2 persons and I have another requirement of job specific chats, so have bound it with it too. Now my conversation channel is like conversation-(talk_id)-(listern_id)-job_id so it all good now. Following are changes I did
1. I removed channel file from assets/javascript as it is automatically load on my application, but I want to bound it with few parameters so I added it to specific view. My controller has already few parameters so I have changed this javascript to following

```
<script>
App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: "ConversationChannel",
    job_id: <%= @job.id %>, 
    contractor: <%= @contractor %>
  }, {
  connected: function() {},
  disconnected: function() {},

  received: function(data) {
    var conversation = $('#conversations-list').find("[data-conversation-id='" + data['conversation_id'] + "']");
    conversation.find('.messages-list').find('ul').append(data['message']);

    var messages_list = conversation.find('.messages-list');
    var height = messages_list[0].scrollHeight;
    messages_list.scrollTop(height);
  },

  speak: function(message) {
    return this.perform('speak', {
      message: message
    });
  }
  });
```

Now when connection establish it sends both parameters and channel channel properly individual. On my `conversation.rb` I have just minor change

```
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversations-#{current_user.id}-#{params[:contractor]}-#{params[:job_id]}"
  end
```

Now everything working perfectly as per our requirements, each channel is being made with 2 users+job Id so I they can communicate on specific job and with specific users, so there no more other person can listen other conversation. 
Just posting may help someone.